# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC Display Id in a input-form as a Select

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an application were I am working with employees.
Every employee has their own ID they recieve when being created.

But I am working with diffrent roles also, for example Mananger Id.
I have a form, which at this moment just is an ordinary input-form where the user can write in any kind of number, for example "12515215".

I want to make so the already existing Ids of the employees is selectable in that form instead. So the user dont have a another choice but to choose one of those Ids already existing in the database.
This is my controller action:

```
region Create Employees
        public IActionResult AddEmployee()
        {
            return View();
        }

    // Create employees
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployee([Bind("Id,FirstName,LastName,Salary,IsCEO,IsManager,ManangerId")] Employee employee)
    {
         
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(employee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(employee);
    }
    #endregion
```

This is how the Razorpage looks like.

```
@model TheLibrary.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add New Employee";
}

<h1>Add new Employee</h1>

<h4>Employee</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddEmployee">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Add a rank number between 1-10 to calculate salary</p>
                <label asp-for="Salary" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Salary" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Salary" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsCEO" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsCEO)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsManager" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsManager)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ManangerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ManangerId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ManangerId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Employee" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

And the model

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Range(1, 10)]
        [Required]
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public bool IsCEO { get; set; }
        public bool IsManager { get; set; }
        public int ManangerId { get; set; }
    }
```

The Primary ID key and this "ManangerId" is part of the same model.
Any Idea on how to change it so I can add the existing Ids as a select instead of just an ordinary input form, in my razorpage?

Comment: You have to show your controller action and a full view.  And Manager and User classes also.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment! I edited my question with all the relevent code, the controller action and the full razor page, and the model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.
Since in my Default.cs file i had

```
@model IEnumerable<Employee>

<select>
    @foreach(var e in Model)
            {
                <option value="@e.Id">@e.Id - @e.FirstName @e.LastName</option>
            }
</select>
```

And in my view I had

```
<div id="TheManagerId" class="form-group">
                <label>Here is my label I want to modify with jQuery</label>
                <label id="ManagerLabel" asp-for="ManangerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select name="ManangerId" asp-for="ManangerId" class="form-control">
                    <option>@await Component.InvokeAsync("Managers") </option>
                </select>
```

I simply removed the `<select>` in the Default.cs file and the `<option>` in the
razor view.
So this is how both files look like
Default.cs:

```
 @foreach(var e in Model)
            {
                <option value="@e.Id">@e.Id - @e.FirstName @e.LastName</option>
            }
```

And razor view:

```
<div id="TheManagerId" class="form-group">
                <label>Here is my label I want to modify with jQuery</label>
                <label id="ManagerLabel" asp-for="ManangerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select name="ManangerId" asp-for="ManangerId" class="form-control">
                    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Managers")
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ManangerId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store all the Manager Id as `List<SelectItem>` in the ViewBag, and use `select` tag with tag-helper to render the List.

For example:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<int> managerids = new List<int>() { 1001, 1002, 1003 };
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach(var id in managerids)
    {
        items.Add(new SelectListItem {  Text = id.ToString(), Value = id.ToString() });
    }
    ViewBag.Manager = items;
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="ManangerId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="ManangerId" asp-items="@(ViewBag.Manager as List<SelectListItem>)" class="form-control"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="ManangerId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created a ViewModel with the exact same code as Employee.cs in my first post
I also created an components folder in the project, with a file called Managers.cs.
Managers.cs file:

```
public class Managers : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;

        public Managers(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int? id)
        {
            var managers = _context.Employees.Where(x => x.IsManager).ToList();

            return View(managers);
        }
```

And I also added an Components folder within the shared folder in the views, in the Components folder i added an Managers folder. So Views > Shared > Components > Managers
In the Managers folder i added
Default.cs

```
@model IEnumerable<Employee>

<select>
    @foreach(var e in Model)
            {
                <option value="@e.Id">@e.Id - @e.FirstName @e.LastName</option>
            }
</select>
```

And this is my razor syntax

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ManangerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ManangerId"  class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ManangerId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
                @await Component.InvokeAsync("Managers")
```

The last line of code displays the Managers id and name, as I wish it to do.
But what should I do to add that line of code within the "Input" element ?

Comment: Why add it to a input element?

Comment: At the moment, the input element for managerID is just an regular input where the user can add any kind of number. I want it to only display existing ids of managers. I have the existing ids of all managers in the view component already.

Comment: So basically I want it to be just like the code example you did, but since I already have started and gotten quite far with my code I would like to try and finish it this way.
Any idea on how it could be done?

Comment: I think there is no problem with your codes,  you just need to add a name attribute to the select tag like `<select name="ManangerId">`, then the selected option value will be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
<div id="TheManagerId" class="form-group">
                <label>Here is my label I want to modify with jQuery</label>
                <label id="ManagerLabel" asp-for="ManangerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select name="ManangerId" asp-for="ManangerId" class="form-control">
                    <option>@await Component.InvokeAsync("Managers") </option>
                </select>
```

But then this append instead:
Instead of the Id inside the select, I got it outside the select
[image]